# Sklearn: How to add association rules to MultinomialNB for text classification?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

**Problem** : `To classify the user product as banned or approved`.

Product will be marked as banned if it contains banned word like "***endangered species***", "***tiger skin***", etc.

- *Input*: Title + description of product
- *Corresponding Labels*: Approved / Banned

I used *supervised learning* algorithm ***MultinomialNB*** to classify the products, it gave the accuracy of 92% with bigrams.

But I have a problem of misclassification in which products of "tiger skin" are getting approved. The reason for this is we have lot of products of "tiger skin granite / tiger skin prawns" which was marked as approved.

In order to solve this problem I want to create some ***rules*** along with MultinomialNB algorithm, to improve those misclassification.

Rules should be like this :- if keyword "tiger" also has granite/prawns at nearby 3/4 words then mark/consider it as approved.

Please help me here. How can I do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you might want to try would be to use another type of classifier, for example `GradientBoostedClassifier`, which can capture interactions between your variables; this might solve your problem. Otherwise you could just use regular expressions to implement your custom rules:

```
import re
if re.search(tiger (\w+ ){0,4}(prawn|granite),text):
   return 'allowed'
```

Comment: For GradientBoostedClassifier: 

But isn't the Naive bayes more appropriate for text classification as compared to decision trees. Moreover it is taking so much time and memory due to which python kernel in ipython is keep dying.

isn't the regex approach will be more manual

Comment: So Naive Bayes is good for some basic text classifications problems like Spam filtering, but it's not good when there are dependences between the words --- you're case is demonstrating this limitation perfectly. If it's taking too much memory, you should probably limit the number of features to around 500-1000 by using dimensionality reduction (eg PCA or NMF) before modelling

Comment: Ok thanks max, yeah currently i have around 1.2 million features..
i will try as per your suggestion and will reply back to you...